# NSCalendar currentCalendar returns nil when called inside cocoapod?

Tags: ios, nsdate, cocoapods, nscalendar

I'm working on a category for NSDate to add methods such as [date isEquivalentToToday]. I had the category working great and then moved into a custom cocoapod.  As soon as I did that it stopped working.  It turns out it's because [NSCalendar currentCalendar] and [calendar components:fromDate] don't seem to work at all when they're called within a cocoapod.  Can anyone explain why that is and if there's a way to make this work?

If you need some code to look at this is what I was doing at the top of isEquivalentToToday:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

When this code is included in the app itself, it returns an NSDate representing today with a time component of zero.

As soon as I move this same code into a cocoapod and have my app call it, the first two lines return nil.

I tried passing a valid NSCalendar object into the cocoapod, but then the components:fromDate: method still returns nil.

I'd rather not just pull this code back into my project since it's nice having it split out into a reusable pod.  But right now I don't see any other way to get this working again.  Anyone else run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending more time looking into it, it looks like the code is actually functioning correctly, but the debugger isn't reporting the correct information when I step into the pod or stop on a breakpoint inside it.

I was able to fix the issue by moving this code back into my main project.

Comment: Experienced the same behavior right now. currentCalendar returns nil according to the debugger but on logging it is there.

Comment: See my recent edit:  In my situation, I was able to fix the problem by just moving the calendar code from the cocoapod I had made, back into my main project.